# Issue with metamask new version

Tags: metamask

smart contract containing Payable function is not working when deployed using new version of metamask. can anyone please resolve this issue?

Comment: You will need to provide more information, such as the relevant code, and sample transaction call.

Comment: solidity code:
pragma solidity ^0.4.21;


contract test1{
    
    mapping(address=>uint) public balances;
    
    function ()public payable{
        
        balances[msg.sender]+=msg.value;
    }
}
and this is deployed in ropsten Test Network 
 contract address is 0x737843b00794aebe122420a6e2f8b99586ce8806 
try sending test ethers to this contract and transaction fails always

Comment: and same contract's fallback function works when deployed using old version of metamask and sending ethers using old version of metamask to this contract

Comment: @HarshaSunny Please, edit your own question and add the code, so it more easy to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just sent some ether to your contract and it fails. The issue seems to be that metamask is making a wrong estimation of the required gas. It asks for a gas limit of about 39500 gas, but looking at your contract the limit should be at least 41000 gas.

I set a gas limit of 100000 gas and it works, consuming 41325 gas.

here is the successful transaction: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x631762aed20ac432fe82d4fc8521c0c7af370a3d34f64f3dd778017854bc37d6

Hope this helps.